# Compare XPATH attributes

Tags: xml, xpath

Why does my code not work? I basically have to check if the person is mentioned in "abgebildet" (so i the compared emails but it does not work for some reason)

```
socialnetwork/personen/person[@email = person/photos/photo/abgebildet/@personemail]/@vorname
```

XML:

```
<socialnetwork>
<personen>
    <person email="H.Mueller@yahoo.com" vorname="Hannah" nachname="Müller" geburtsdatum="1991-02-02">
        <photos>
            <photo url="http://www.flickr.com/myphoto/H.Mueller/147.jpg" titel="Photo Number 147" beschreibung="This is a very nice picture taken by H.Mueller@yahoo.com">
                <abgebildet personemail="F.Kaiser@yahoo.com"/>
                <abgebildet personemail="Laura.Heinrich@gmail.com"/>
                <abgebildet personemail="Lucas.Bergmann@sms.at"/>
                <abgebildet personemail="M.Krause@sms.at"/>
                <abgebildet personemail="Neele.Schmitt@yahoo.com"/>
                <abgebildet personemail="P.Winkler@gmx.net"/>
                <abgebildet personemail="S.Hofmann@live.at"/>
                <abgebildet personemail="S.Sommer@gmx.net"/>
            </photo>
```

Comment: Because no `@personemail` matches `@email`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Update your XML to include a possible match, because as @JackFleeting comments, no `@personemail` matches `@email`.
2. Update your XML to include a `@vorname`, because it has no such attribute currently, or drop `@vorname` from your XPath.
3. Change your predicate from

   ```
   person[@email = person/photos/photo/abgebildet/@personemail]
   ```

   to

   ```
   person[@email = photos/photo/abgebildet/@personemail]
   ```

   because the current node is already a `person` element within the predicate.